# Volume in tropical geometry as compared to volume in convex geometry

Tags: convex-geometry, tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

In tropical geometry, is there a notion of volume. Maybe one with some of the properties as found in classical convex geometry? If so, is there a good reference that elaborates on this question.

I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118872/volume-in-tropical-geometry) question here, but apparently the answers did not consider volume.

Answer (score 1):

I think a certain generalization of volume in tropical geometry is given by Monge-Ampere measure. See http://www2.math.su.se/reports/2000/10/2000-10.pdf  (M. Passare and H. Rullgard, Amoebas, Monge-Ampere measures, and triangulations of the Newton polytope) and http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2856 (A. Lagerberg, Super currents and tropical geometry).